# Is it possible to exclude all tags related to third-party libraries?

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I want to get some reputation by answering. But when I filter questions by tags, I mostly find tags related to third-party libraries.

[image: Ignored tags]

**EDIT:** Not all tags mentioned above are third-party libraries.

I tried to use the `Ignored Tags` section, but it seems to be useful for excluding programming languages, the amount of third-party libraries is so big I doubt I could exclude all of them. So I'm looking for a shortcut, like excluding ALL third-party libraries from the `interesting` section and searches.

#### NOTE

(Sorry for my English here)
I know it's least likely such feature exist, but not everybody knows the site at 100%, so it could exist.

Comment: Ultimately it would be nice if only people asking questions about the language used the language tag, and people asking questions about the library used the library tags. Sadly such an approach does not scale to the size of Stack Overflow. There is currently no way to differentiate between language tags and library/framework tags (provided by Stack Overflow, it is possible that someone has concocted a method of achieving the task but I haven't heard anything to that effect).

Comment: There were a couple of requests for tags to indicate non-library usage of tags (eg vanilla-javascript) but what you'd really need is a search that whitelisted given tags instead of blacklisting everything you don't want.